# Where to make a POST to for crumbs url shortening service Advanced API

Tags: php, html, api, post, url-shortener

I have a PHP/JavaScript site (offline). I am using http://crum.bs/ for shortening URLs.

Here, there are 2 types of APIs provided by crum.bs:

1. Simple Shorten, and
2. Advanced Shorten

I am currently using the simple shorten API. The base URL to make a GET request is `http://crum.bs/api.php?function=simpleshorten&url=[insert url here]`.

Now, I am planning to change it to the advanced API which requires POST.

I can't find the Base for this anywhere on that page (Or in Google).
The API Reference Page is http://blog.crum.bs/?p=12. Does anybody know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you would submit your POST request to the same path

```
http://crum.bs/api.php
```

You just need to pass the variables in the request (which technically would look the same as the Simple version, just a different HTTP verb is used)

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://crum.bs/api.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'url' => 'http://www.some-really-long-url.com/with/a/lot/of/text/etc.html',
        'desc' => 'some other data',
    ),
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The $result var will contain the JSON response from crum.bs service

Comment: I tried this. It redirects to http://crum.bs/api.php. I even tried POSTing it through <form>. Didn't work

Comment: Yeah, afraid I'll put my hand up and say I answered with what should work based on their docs. Now I've tried it I get the same issue.  Any POST call to their API returned the API documentation not the JSON.

Comment: is there any other service i could use for shortening links with API?

Comment: Without wanting to give a crap answer, you could try googling that.  I did and first hit was a page listing 71 shortener services.  Bit.ly is the one I've seen the most of.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for that. I Dont use bitly for a reason. I want a service with passwords. Will find it myself

Comment: No worries.  Crumbs looks interesting, I've sent them a query about their POST api docs as they don't seem complete (or the POST api isn't working)